# Hi, I am doing the java code found below, for a login form.It is not redirecting me to the employee.jsp or customer jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, session, javabeans, login-script

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        user user = new user();
        user.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
        user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        user = loginBean.Login(user);
        if (user.getMessage() == null || user.getMessage().equals("")) {
            request.setAttribute("message", user.getMessage());
        }
        if (user.getRole().equals("Employee")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/employee.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/customer.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: What **is** it doing?

Comment: Did you try debugging the code to see what's going on? Does the `processRequest` gets called at all?

Comment: The whole code is running but only the code i pasted above is not working. The login page works well and i can put username and password. When i press the submit button, it does not give anything.

Comment: How are you using this code? If it is in servlet then make sure you invoke it in its `doPost` method.

Comment: I am using java derby database for storing purposes.

Comment: I am using servlet for the code.

Comment: method names shall be lower cased: loginBean.Login

Comment: Servlets doesn't have `processRequest` method. You need to invoke it explicitly in one of its methods, most probably in `doPost` which handles data from `<form method='post' ...>`.

Comment: ah ok, will try that. thanks.
But is there any problems that I am getting due to derby database.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is after a successful login redirect the user to employee.jsp or customer.jsp depending on their role.

You currently forward the request on to employee.jsp or customer.jsp along with all the parameters (username, password and message and anything else).

What you need to do is redirect the user to the new page like this:

```
if (user.getRole().equals("Employee")) {
    response.sendRedirect("/employee.jsp");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("/customer.jsp");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make  Sure that u had these pages in your project directory . If they are not there you get error message.
 your code is right

```
 if (user.getRole().equals("Employee")) {
response.sendRedirect("/employee.jsp");} else {
response.sendRedirect("/customer.jsp");}
```